# Spring JPA custom query - is possible to use input as logic operator

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, jpa

Is possible to use input as logic operator in custom query?
I created custom query which returns list of objects with area less or equal paramter:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SHAPES WHERE COUNT_AREA(TYPE, RADIUS, WIDTH, HEIGHT) <= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShapeEntity> getObjectsWithArea(double area);
```

but is possible to add one more parameter instead of "<="? I would like to add logic operator as input to avoid having two similar queries, something like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SHAPES WHERE COUNT_AREA(TYPE, RADIUS, WIDTH, HEIGHT) ?1 ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShapeEntity> getObjectsWithArea(String operator, double area);
```

instead of nearly equals:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SHAPES WHERE COUNT_AREA(TYPE, RADIUS, WIDTH, HEIGHT) >= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShapeEntity> getObjectsWithGreaterArea(double area);

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SHAPES WHERE COUNT_AREA(TYPE, RADIUS, WIDTH, HEIGHT) <= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<ShapeEntity> getObjectsWithLessArea(double area);
```

Is it possible at all? When I try it I am getting:

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you cannot use `@Query`.

Write the implementation of `getObjectsWithArea(String operator, double area)` forging your query with

```
TypedQuery<ShapeEntity> q = entityManager.createQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM SHAPES WHERE COUNT_AREA(TYPE, RADIUS, WIDTH, HEIGHT) %s :ca", operator), ShapeEntity.class);
q.setParameter("ca", theWantedValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I set up "?1"? I found only solution with ":name" and q.setParameter("name", name)

Comment: You are right. I have changed my answer. But the parameter numbering is also possible with : `q.setParameter(1, theWantedValue)`